# Disable cache in Selenium Chrome Driver

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, selenium4

I’m using the Selenium ChromeDriver in order to measure performance of web pages. But by default in Chrome driver cache is enabled.

Option `--disable-application-cache` is deprecated now https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=447206

Also I can initialize a new instanсe of driver each time, but it is not very convenient.

My question is there a way for properly disable cache?

Thanks!

Comment: I had seen this to work in the case of IE, you should find similar capability for Chrome. `capabilities={'ie.ensureCleanSession': True}`. Using this, you always ensured you ran a clean instance of the browser.

Answer (score 5):

In Chrome Dev tools Network tab we can disable the cache by clicking on 'Disable Cache' checkbox. [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7000899/5324105)

Same behavior can be replicated using the **Chrome DevTools Protocol** support in the Selenium 4.

We can use ['Network.setCacheDisabled'](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-setCacheDisabled) from Chrome DevTools Protocol

```
Toggles ignoring cache for each request. If true, cache will not be used.
parameters

cacheDisabled
    boolean

    Cache disabled state.
```

**Example is from the Selenium Test for DevTools**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.network.Network;

 @Test
  public void verifyCacheDisabledAndClearCache() {

    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    DevTools devTools = driver.getDevTools();
    devTools.createSession();
   

    devTools.send(Network.enable(Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(), Optional.of(100000000)));

    driver.get("http://www.google.com");

    devTools.send(Network.setCacheDisabled(true));

    devTools.addListener(Network.responseReceived(), responseReceived -> assertEquals(false, responseReceived.getResponse().getFromDiskCache()));

   driver.get("http://www.google.com");

    devTools.send(Network.clearBrowserCache());

  }
```

getFromDiskCache() -- Specifies if request was served from the disk cache.

For above code it will be `false`

You can refer the **selenium repository** for all the example tests [devtools/ChromeDevToolsNetworkTest.java](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/java/client/test/org/openqa/selenium/devtools/ChromeDevToolsNetworkTest.java#L214)

**For Dev Tools Maven Dependency**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-devtools -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-devtools</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0-alpha-6</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned, the option `--disable-application-cache` is deprecated now.

You can use `--disk-cache-size` and set it to `zero`. This will force the maximum disk space to be used by the disk cache to be zero. Although it may not work on some of the older browsers. I successfully tested it for firefox v67.0.1

Refer this command list for more details: https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Answer (score 0):

### Disable Cache in Google Chrome

You noted it right. There have been several discussions regarding the flag *`--disable-application-cache`* in the following discussions:

- [Issue 447206: Removing --disable-application-cache and --disable-session-storage command-line flags](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=447206)
- [Command line flags that should be considered for removal](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=343941)

Both the items seems to blocked on certain other dependencies.

---

### Manually accessing `Disable cache`

The option to `Disable cache` of [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) can be accessed from the **Network** tab within [google-chrome-devtools](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-devtools).

[image: Disable cache]

### Keyboard shortcuts for opening DevTools

Manually you can use either of the following [Keyboard shortcuts for opening DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/shortcuts#open):

[image: Keyboard shortcuts for opening DevTools]

> You can find a relevant discussion in [Opening inspect (pressing F12) on Chrome via Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59365968/opening-inspect-pressing-f12-on-chrome-via-selenium/59369763#59369763)

---

### ChromeDevtoolsProtocol support through [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491)

With the availability [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) the support for *ChromeDevtoolsProtocol(CDP)* is now available through the `DevTools` interface.

- *v4.0.0.0-alpha-1*: Basic support for CDP landed via the "DevTools" interface.
- *v4.0.0.0-alpha-2*: Extra domains added for CDP: Network, Performance, Security, Target
- *v4.0.0-alpha-3*: Add ApplicationCache, Fetch, Network, Performance, Profiler, ResourceTiming, Security and Target CDP domains.
- *v4.0.0-alpha-4*: Chrome Debugging Protocol commands now mirror latest CDP spec.
- *v4.0.0-alpha-6*: Ability to proxy CDP commands from the local end through the fully-distributed Grid. The end point to connect to is reported via "se:options -> cdp"

---

### Network.setCacheDisabled

The [Network.setCacheDisabled](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-setCacheDisabled) can be used to toggle ignoring cache for each request. If `true`, cache will not be used.

- Usage:

  ```
  devTools.send(Network.setCacheDisabled(true));
  ```

---

### Demonstration

Here is a demonstration on the usage of [`setCacheDisabled(true)`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/df045c8ab6a87e33c6069901fc0acdd3b7e5e49f/java/client/test/org/openqa/selenium/devtools/ChromeDevToolsNetworkTest.java#L220):

Environment details:

- *Selenium v4.0.0-alpha-6*
- *ChromeDriver 83.0.4103.39 (2020-05-05)*
- *Google Chrome Version 83.0.4103.116*
- *TestNG*

Code Block:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.DevTools;
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.network.Network;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class testngBasic {

    @Test
    public void foo() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\WebDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
        options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        DevTools devTools = driver.getDevTools();
        devTools.createSession();
        devTools.send(Network.enable(Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(), Optional.of(100000000)));
        devTools.send(Network.setCacheDisabled(true));
        devTools.addListener(Network.responseReceived(), responseReceived -> Assert.assertEquals(false, responseReceived.getResponse().getFromDiskCache()));
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        devTools.send(Network.clearBrowserCache());
  }
}
```

Conclusion: Asserting `responseReceived.getResponse().getFromDiskCache()` as **`false`** establishes that **cache was disabled**

Answer (score -4):

I was facing a similar, used `driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();` before navigating to the page whose performance needs to be checked. This way we get a fresh instance of the browser every time we load a page.
This works for Firefox as well as Chrome driver without any issues.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Cache can include more than just cookies. This doesn't answer the question and is a bad work around.