# Timeout exception when using dev tools with selenium-java-4.0.0 and chromedriver v85

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools, selenium4

I'm trying to use selenium dev tools java API, and for multiple API methods I'm getting `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException`.

For example I'm trying to use `Network.clearBrowserCache`, which should work accroding to chromedriver docs: https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/

I'm calling `clearBrowserCache` using following code:
`chromeDriver.getDevTools().send(Network.clearBrowserCache())`

It fails, but at the same time if I use other devTools commands like this:
`chromeDriver.getDevTools().send(Browser.getVersion())`

It returns data properly.

- Chrome version is: 85.0.4183.39
- Chromedriver version is: 85.0.4183.87
- Selenium-java version is: 4.0.0-alpha-6

Answer (score 6):

Try calling `createSession` before calling `clearBrowserCache`.

Using your setup, this works:

```
chromeDriver.getDevTools().createSession();
chromeDriver.getDevTools().send(Network.clearBrowserCache())
```

and this produces `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException`:

```
chromeDriver.getDevTools().send(Network.clearBrowserCache())
```

You can verify that the browser cache has been cleared with this snippet:

```
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://refreshyourcache.com/en/cache-test/");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.getDevTools().createSession();
    driver.getDevTools().send(Network.clearBrowserCache());
    driver.get("https://refreshyourcache.com/en/cache-test/");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
```

If you run the code, the pages displayed in the test browser will show these images:
[image]

If you commment out the line `driver.getDevTools().send(Network.clearBrowserCache());` then you get a different result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, it fixes the original issue - 'clearBrowserCache' returns without error, but it doesn't do the job - I see that cache hasn't been cleared, maybe it's another unrelated issue, anyway maybe you have ideas how to fix that?

Comment: I've added a code example for verifying the result of calling `clearBrowserCache()`.

Answer (score 3):

Using *Selenium 4.0.0-alpha-6*, *Chrome v85* and *ChromeDriver v85.0* through [google-chrome-devtools](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-devtools) you must be able to use [`getVersion()`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Browser/#method-getVersion) method as follows:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.DevTools;
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.browser.Browser;

public class BrowserGetVersion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\WebDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        DevTools devTools = driver.getDevTools();
        devTools.createSession();
        devTools.send(Browser.getVersion());
    }
}
```

Similarly, using the [`clearBrowserCache()`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-clearBrowserCache) method you should be able to clear the browser cache using the following code block:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.DevTools;
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.network.Network;

public class ClearChromeCache {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\WebDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        DevTools devTools = driver.getDevTools();
        devTools.createSession();
        devTools.send(Network.clearBrowserCache());
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    }
}
```

---

### Additional Consideration

Additionally, you can also use [`setCacheDisabled(true)`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/df045c8ab6a87e33c6069901fc0acdd3b7e5e49f/java/client/test/org/openqa/selenium/devtools/ChromeDevToolsNetworkTest.java#L220) to completely **disable** the *cache* as follows:

Code Block:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.DevTools;
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.network.Network;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class testngBasic {

    @Test
    public void foo() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\WebDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
        options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        DevTools devTools = driver.getDevTools();
        devTools.createSession();
        devTools.send(Network.clearBrowserCache());
        devTools.send(Network.enable(Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(), Optional.of(100000000)));
        devTools.send(Network.setCacheDisabled(true));
        devTools.addListener(Network.responseReceived(), responseReceived -> Assert.assertEquals(false, responseReceived.getResponse().getFromDiskCache()));
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");

  }
}
```

---

### This usecase

Possibly your code have nothing to do with `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException` error and the real issue is either with the:

- **jdk** version
- **guava** version

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to current levels [JDK 8u252](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *guava* is upgraded to **guava-29.0-jre**.

### Outro

[Disable cache in Selenium Chrome Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29988227/disable-cache-in-selenium-chrome-driver/62816335#62816335)

Comment: Thank you, creating session before using commands is the point I was missing, but unfortunately when I verify if cache is really cleared (by comparing number of requests being actually sent by browser to my server) I see that behavior is the same as if I didn't call 'clear browser cache' at all - requests seem to be cached. At the same time if I restart driver - I'm getting clear session & cache and my tests pass, so they are correct

Comment: @XZen Checkout the answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: Thank you, setCacheDisabled works as expected, but in my case I need to clear cache at some moment, not to completely disable it

Comment: @XZen Great News !!! Glad to help you out !!! `setCacheDisabled` works per request basis. In the next line of code or operation it would be set as `disabled` again. Let me know the results of your test. By the mean time I will try to pull out something more catering to your usecase.

Answer (score 2):

It worked fine

```
public void testCdt {
    final ChromeLauncher launcher = new ChromeLauncher();
    final ChromeService chromeService = launcher.launch(false);
    final ChromeTab tab = chromeService.createTab();
    final ChromeDevToolsService devToolsService = chromeService.createDevToolsService(tab);
    final Page page = devToolsService.getPage();
    Network network = devToolsService.getNetwork();
    // Clear browser cached
    network.clearBrowserCache();
    // Log requests with onRequestWillBeSent event handler.
    network.onRequestWillBeSent(
            event ->
                    System.out.printf(
                            "request: %s %s%s",
                            event.getRequest().getMethod(),
                            event.getRequest().getUrl(),
                            System.lineSeparator()));

    network.onLoadingFinished(
            event -> {
              chromeService.closeTab(tab);
              launcher.close();
            });
    network.enable();
    page.navigate("http://github.com");
    devToolsService.waitUntilClosed();
  }
```